# ob_start not executing callback

Tags: php, ob-start

I'm having issues with ob_start.  Not sure what the deal is, but I've bubbled it down to the simplest possible test case... still to no avail.  I would expect this code to output 'bar' to the stdout, but I'm getting nothing back, and no errors in my error log.

```
<?php
function gzhandler_ex($buffer, $mode)
{
    echo 'bar';
}

ob_start('gzhandler_ex');
echo 'foo';
ob_flush();
```

I've never seen this before, but I don't typically use callbacks like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your handler function should `return` the content you want to output, not echo it.

```
function gzhandler_ex($buffer, $mode)
{
    return 'bar';
}
```

Also, the `ob_flush()` is unnecessary when called at the end of the script; it is implicit.

Comment: Facepalm.  Thanks much, I knew it had to be something so baseline.